# ¿Como evaluar los registros optenidos con SELECT para obtener el mejor?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos en Mysql 5.6 y tengo una tabla donde se registran los Conductores, la base de datos se utiliza para administrar los viajes de un sitio de taxis, funciona de la siguiente manera:

Un cliente solicita un viaje, y ese viaje se registra en una tabla llamada viajes_pendientes, y Postulantes, en esta tabla de Postulantes los Conductores se registran automaticamente, registran informacion como Distancia entre el y el usuario, Calidad del onductor y dinero acomulado en todo el dia.

el viaje se le asignara al operador que este a menos de 1km de distancia, pero si hay mas de 1 operador dentro de ese rango entonces se le dara al que este a menos de 1km y tenga mejor calidad, y si aun asi siguen habiendo mas de 1 operador entonces se le da a aquel que tenga menos dinero acumulado en el dia.

mi problema es que en Mysql, si indico que me seleccione al que tiene menos dinero acumulado con la sentencia MIN(dinero), puede seleccionarme a uno que este fuera del kilometro permitido, y si junto las sentencias (Distancia<1000) AND MAX(Calidad) AND MIN(dinero), me manda error, o bueno, mejor dicho, no selecciona ningun registro, por que el que tiene mejor calidad es el que tiene mas dinero, o esta fuera de la distancia, etc.

¿Es posible evaluar la segunda (calidad) condicion solo a los registros que cumplan con la primera condicion (distancia)? y obviamente, que solo se evalue la tercera condicion(dinero) a los que ya cumpliron con las dos primeras?

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar el SQL para crear esta tabla? ¿Y la consulta SQL que utilizas? Ésto nos permitiría hacer pruebas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la distancia como criterio de búsqueda y las otras de ordenación, de la siguiente menera, recuperando luego los registros que requieras.

```
SELECT * FROM conductores
WHERE (Distancia < 1000) ORDER BY MAX(Calidad), MIN(dinero) ASC
```